# PySpark sorting the sorted

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

Please help a beginner. 
Usual db for order placement, all in one table.

Analyzing data in Apache Spark using Python. Want to write a query that would pull all transactions of customers sorted by email that ordered a product that is discontinued now, and have orders that were not shipped yet. Basically with "&item_in_list(F.lit("NotShipped"), ShippedStatus)" it's not working.

```
%python
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

list_len = F.udf(lambda x: len(x), IntegerType())
item_in_list = F.udf(lambda x, y: x in y, BooleanType())
df = spark.sql("select * from orderdb")
df1 = df.select("email", "OrderedProduct","ShippedStatus").groupBy("email")
df1 = df1.agg(F.collect_set("OrderedProduct"))\
       .withColumnRenamed("collect_set(OrderedProduct)", "OrderedProduct")
df1 = df1.filter((list_len(df1.OrderedProduct) > 1) & 
               item_in_list(F.lit("DiscontinuedProduct"), OrderedProduct) 
        &item_in_list(F.lit("NotShipped"), ShippedStatus)

df1 = df1.select("email")
df = df1.join(df, "email", "left_outer")
display(df)
```

ID string null
date DateTimestamp null
OrderedProduct string null
ShippedStatus boolean null

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **udf's perform very bad in pyspark**. If you want to change the types, use something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

df = df.withColumn("column", df["column"].cast(IntegerType()))
```

That being said, we need a reproducible example for the rest, but I guess you can solve it with `'where'` clause.

```
# Your code
df1 = df1.filter((list_len(df1.OrderedProduct) > 1) & 
               item_in_list(F.lit("DiscontinuedProduct"), OrderedProduct) 
        &item_in_list(F.lit("NotShipped"), ShippedStatus)

# My code
condition1 = F.col('OrderedProduct') > 1
condition2 = F.col('ShippedStatus') == F.lit('NotShipped')
condition3 = F.col('OrderedProduct') == F.lit('DiscontinuedProduct')

df1 = df1.where(condition 1 & condition2 & condition3)
```